# ¿Porque no funciona este query en codeigniter, y en la IDE de ms Access funciona sin problema? (Creo que es el JOIN)

Tags: json, codeigniter, sql, ms-access, join

Tengo un query que no consigo hacer funcionar dentro de codeigniter, quitando partes del query, parece ser que el error esta en el JOIN, pero no entiendo porque, y aún menos entiendo, que al realizar el query en PostMan, por ejemplo, no da ningun error, simplemente se queda el resultado en "blanco" (Utilizando querys simples el resutado es correcto)

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT F_STO.ARTSTO, F_STO.ACTSTO, F_STO.MINSTO, F_ART.DESART
                      FROM F_STO RIGHT JOIN F_ART ON F_STO.ARTSTO = F_ART.CODART
                      WHERE F_STO.ACTSTO < F_STO.MINSTO AND F_STO.ARTSTO LIKE 'T%'
                      ");
```

La conexión es a una base de datos MS Access (no por gusto...) usando el driver ODBC.

Si en lugar de usar result_array() para ver el valor utilizo este codigo:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT F_STO.ARTSTO, F_STO.ACTSTO, F_STO.MINSTO, F_ART.DESART, F_ART.CODART
                                                        FROM F_STO
                                                        RIGHT JOIN F_ART ON F_STO.ARTSTO = F_ART.CODART
                                                        WHERE F_STO.ACTSTO < F_STO.MINSTO AND F_STO.ARTSTO LIKE 'T%'
                                                        ");
$respuesta = array(

  'error' => FALSE,
  'stock' => $query->num_rows()
);
$this->response($respuesta);
```

Si que me da la cantidad de filas que hay en el resultado, que en este caso es 1.

Pero si lo hago asi:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT F_STO.ARTSTO, F_STO.ACTSTO, F_STO.MINSTO, F_ART.DESART, F_ART.CODART
                          FROM F_STO
                          RIGHT JOIN F_ART ON F_STO.ARTSTO = F_ART.CODART
                          WHERE F_STO.ACTSTO < F_STO.MINSTO AND F_STO.ARTSTO LIKE 'T%'
                          ");

    $respuesta = array(

      'error' => FALSE,
      'stock' => $query->result_array()
    );
    $this->response($respuesta);
```

No me muestra ni el 'error','false', se queda totalmente en blanco.

Muchas Gracias, espero que me podais echar una mano.

EDITADO: SOLUCIÓN

El query era correcto, el problema estaba al generar el JSON, no se porque desde POSTMAN no me daba ningun error de JSON incorrecto, pero desde el inspector de Firefox me marcaba

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

Revisando el contenido de la base de datos me di cuenta de que algunas filas tenian una

> "

No era contenido entre comillado, pero tenia que estar en la base porque hace referencia a le medida de una rosca, por ejemplo 2" NPT.

Al quitar las comillas para hacer la prueba ya se formó el JSON correctamente.

Ahora solo me queda investigar como sustituir las comillas antes de formar el JSON, pero eso ya es otra historia.

Gracias

Comment: Tu query no está trayendo resultados. Ese num_rows() devuelve 1 porque lo estas usando como si fuera una propiedad, pero es un método. Ese "1" realmente es un "true", que quiere decir que el método se ejecuto bien, por lo que ese 1 no quiere decir que este trayendo resultados. (prueba agregando otro elemento a la BD y seguirá siendo 1).

Ahora respecto a la consulta, si copias y pegas en el cliente de la base de datos (copiar y pegar tal cual) trae resultados?.

De ser así, estas 100% seguro que estas apuntando a la misma base de datos? mismo ambiente?

Comment: Si, estoy seguro al 100% que es la misma base de datos. Incluso si quito el like y el join, el row me da unos 6000 registros que son los que hay en la BD, y en access funciona correctamente. Lo que mas raro me parece es que no devuelve absolutamente nada, ninlsnpsrte del error que tendría que salir siempre, ya que está dentro del response

Comment: Prueba usando $this->db->_error_message(); de haber algun error saldrá con ese método. Si no esta mostrando nada, es que Codeigniter tienes los errores desactivados, revisa tu index.php y ve que ENV estas usando, puedes, temporalmente cambiar a error_reporting(E_ALL); y ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Lo que debe estar ocurriendo, es que ese result_array esta arrojando una excepcion y no la estas viendo pq los errores estan desactivados

Comment: @Vertig0 , ya he revisado lo del Enviorement, y esta en development con todos los errores activados. El `$this->db->_error_message()` me dice que no encuentra la función, en cambio si utilizado `error()` me devuelve `esto {"code":"","message":""}`. Con el query de arriba, dejando el join, y con el num_rows me devuelve 1438, que es lo mismo que la cantidad de filas que me devuelve Access, lo raro es que al pedir el contenido, no devuelve nada... Gracias

Comment: @Vertig0 viendo el visor de firefox me acabo de dar cuenta de que me marca este error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data y aqui si que ya me he quedado muerto, en codeigniter uso: codeigniter-restserver de chriskacerguis por si puede ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Usaste el db error message? el error de Json es simplemente que no puede parsear, seguramente pq hay una excepcion y esa excepcion tiene formato json

Comment: @Vertig0 ya esta solucionado... era la tonteria mas grande, no era problema del query, sino del JSON que devolvia (como indicas en el ultimo comentario) resulta que en el campo de la base de datos con el que hacia el JOIN habia contenido con '"' pero no porque estuviera entrecomillado, sino porque es como se ponen las pulgadas (ej 2" NPT) y por esa razon el JSON que devolvia era invalido y no mostraba nada y tambien por eso el numero de filas si que las marcaba bien. Muchas gracias y perdona por las molestias. Si puedes, propon respuesta para aceptarla y cerrar la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: No, tranquilo, al final no lo solucione yo :). Lo importante es que se soluciono.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucionaste tu pregunta, viendo tu `consulta` creo que se te facilitaría mas haciendo uso de las `querys` que te facilita `codeigniter` y que te queda algo mucho mas limpio.

Ejemplo:

```
public function tufuncion()
{
    $this->db->select('f.ARTSTO, f.ACTSTO, f.MINSTO, f.DESART');
    $this->db->from('F_STO f');
    $this->db->join('F_ART a','f.ARTSTO = a.CODART','right outer');
    $this->db->where('f.ACTSTO < f.MINSTO');
    $this->db->like('f.ARTSTO', 'T', 'after');

    $aResult = $this->db->get();
    if(!$aResult->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $aResult->result_array();
}
```

Para mas información sobre las `querys` en la [documentación de codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html).

Comment: Desde algunas versiones anteriores de codeigniter, cuando conectas por ODBC no se pueden utilizar los querys de la forma que comentas, por algun comentario que lei, es porque era muy facil hacer un ataque de SQL injection, y por eso esta desactivado.

Comment: @NeWsPi Gracias por el dato!